# Digital Ocean Ubuntu LAMP server: Laravel cannot access router group

Tags: php, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I recently deployed a Laravel 5.1 app to an LAMP setup on Ubuntu on Digital Ocean.

Accessing my Droplet at http://159.203.82.91/ gets me:

> This Works

I've set up a Route prefix of `1.0` (see below), http://159.203.82.91/1.0:

[image]

But it should read

> This does not!

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router) {
        $router->get('/', function () { return 'This Works'; });
        $router->group(['prefix' => App\Http\Controllers\Controller::API_VERSION], function(Router $router) {
                $router->get('/', function () { return 'This does not!'; });
```

Why is it that I can access the `index` but not a subroute like `/1.0`?

---

```
root@phpmyadmin-512mb-nyc3-01:/var/www/html# cat public/.htaccess 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

---[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `public/.htaccess` is there and you used `AllowOverride` directive in apache configuration to allow the use of `.htaccess`?

Comment: @Bilal htaccess is there. See above. Where is `AllowOverride`?

Comment: Have you created a virtual host to map your IP to Laravel's public folder?

Comment: @Bilal no not yet. Is that done in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?

Comment: It depends on where you have put your virtual host configuration. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check following points to fix your problem.

- Verify that you enabled `mode_rewrite` in Apache.
- Verify that you put `AllowOverride` directive in your Apache Virtual host configuration.

[Follow this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite) if you don't know how to do that. From the guide, you just need to see how to enable `mod_rewrite` and editing your default virtual host to allow use of `.htaccess`.

Comment: But there will be `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` directive. You can add 
`<Directory>` section by yourself if its already not there.

Comment: Yes, now restart apache and check.

Comment: after `sudo service apache2 restart` - Nope not working

Comment: Why does mod rewrite need to be enabled?